# Is there a way to differentiate ember serve from Ember build in environment.js?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I would like to either be able to pass an argument in `ember build` that differentiates it from ember serve (http://localhost:4200).

I am trying to have a different `rootURL` when running locally through `localhost:4200` and when it is a build in the dev server using `ember build`  https://www.example.com/app .

Otherwise is it possible to set the default environment of Ember serve to be 'local' instead of 'development?

Comment: you *could* introspec `process.argv` I think

Comment: I think the environment variable will be an apt choice. You can have different deployment/development stages and configure appropriate variables. Check here: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/configuring-ember/configuring-your-app/

Comment: @GokulKathirvel I have already done that.. the problem is that I always get `environment = development` by default if I do `ember s` which is not differentiating it from `ember build --environment=development`

Comment: @Lux I will have to check that process.argv. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research and without  a way to do it with built-in functionality, 
I decided to use  [ember-cli-dotenv](https://github.com/fivetanley/ember-cli-dotenv).

I added a git-ignored `.env` file with `IS_LOCAL = true` for my local and `IS_LOCAL = false` in my development/staging/production environments that are in the servers.